Is there a way to show calendars from multiple persons into one SharePoint list calendar?
I need to show a calendar in SharePoint page. This calendar should show all events of all the persons I need. So it should be like a combination.
I tried creating a flow to get events from the calendar and then creating that as a list item in SharePoint, and then changing the view to Calendar. But this flow is running only for when an event is added, updated or deleted. So it only works for new entries. The already existing events in the calendars of the persons I want is not getting retrieved.
